# Is there a way to catch exception from native code in the js code?

Tags: swift, react-native

lets say I called a native component from the javascript code and that components breaks how I can handle that in my code (JS) is there a mechanism to catch exceptions from the native threads in the JS thread ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://github.com/master-atul/react-native-exception-handler.

> A react native module that lets you to register a global error handler
>   that can capture fatal/non fatal uncaught exceptions. The module helps
>   prevent abrupt crashing of RN Apps without a graceful message to the
>   user.